# how to call javascript function using HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

i have this HTML code, how do i call a javascript function without making changes to my HTML file.

```
<tr>
     <td><div id="number1">1</div></td>
     <td><div>+</div></td>
     <td><div id="number2">2</div></td>
     <td><div>=</div></td>
     <td><input type="text"></input></td>
     <td><input type="button" value="Check"></input></td>
</tr>
```

tried to use this javascript code but didn't work

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
button.onclick = function(){ alert('hello!'); };
```

Comment: I updated my answer,Please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("input");` gives you list of inputs and not just a button.

Here, `button.onclick = function(){ alert('hello!'); };` you are trying to attach click handler to the list itself which is not valid. You have to bind the handler one by one.

*Edited:*

Using `document.querySelector()`:

```js
//gets the input where type is button and value is check
var btn = document.querySelector('input[type=button][value=Check]');
//add click handler
btn.onclick = function() {
  alert('You clicked !');
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Check"></input>
```

Using `document.getElementsByTagName()`:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); //get all inputs
var i = 0;
var btn; //temp for button
var t //temp
while (t = inputs[i++]) { //loop in all inputs for correct button
  //verify if type is `button` and value is `check`
  if (t.type.match(/button/i) && t.value.match(/check/i)) {
    btn = t;
    break;
  }
}
if (btn) { //got the button
  btn.onclick = function() {
    alert('You click me !');
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Not me"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="button" value="Check"></input>
```

Comment: " how do i call a javascript function without making changes to my HTML file." this is his question,read

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  
  button[1].onclick = function(){ button[0].value=3; };
```

1. we should get all input element, result is 2 input element. first is text, second is button
2. then we should use second (button)  button[1]...on click button we call function and in text input write value 3 (1+2=3)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getElementsByTagName` returns all input elements in the DOM, you need to check if the input is of type button like so:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "button") {
        inputs[i].onclick = function () {
            alert("hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hL2kavzs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this using querySelectorAll()

```js
 document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() { alert('hello'); });
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
     <td><div id="number1">1</div></td>
     <td><div>+</div></td>
     <td><div id="number2">2</div></td>
     <td><div>=</div></td>
     <td><input type="text" /> </td>
     <td><input type="button" value="Check" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").addEventListener("click",   function(){
    alert('hello');});
```